# Trying to re-create a certain Kraftwerk sound

Tags: synthesizer, analog, strings

I've been trying to recreate a specific Kraftwerk pad sound - i thought it shouldn't be too difficult, but i can't seem to get it right. It is the pad sound you can hear in It's More Fun to Compute. Its a bit of a stringy sound, and i can hear it has been used as a chord of sorts. It pops out for the first time at 1m20s:

[YouTube link to the track](https://youtu.be/3odl-KoNZwk?t=1m19s)

I have a MiniBrute and several softsynth (Alchemy, most NI stuff and Tone2's Nemesis) and tried to get this string-like sound but for some reason it stays too.. well.. clean (or boring if you will :) ).

Any suggestions on how to set this sound up, where to start and/or what chords/keys have been used for this melody?

Cheers,
J.

Answer (score 1):

I am familiar with the track Its More Fun To Compute.
Kraftwerk, or more importantly, Karl Bartos, played Minimoog and ARP Odyssey synths. 
The best advice, if using a DAW program, is to find a Synth VSTi (virtual instrument) that will emulate those sounds (there are plenty of them , also free ones if you do not wish to buy one) if you cannot emulate the sound you require with what you have.
I hope this helps.